# How to rotate a sphere along the three axis (x,y,z) simultaneously

Tags: javascript, three.js, quaternions, euler-angles

I want to rotate an image along all the three axis in a way that all rotation will be taken in account at suitable order.
Am using `Three Js` library and the rotation seems to work along one axis and with the three axis the rotation is abnormal. I have seen some ideas about rotating using quaternions to avoid gimbal lock and I tried Euler but it was not successful.

***sphericImageMesh_*** is my sphere and ***this.getRollDeg()*** is method to get roll as given by camera.

What I tried is here below:

```
// var euler = new THREE.Euler( - THREE.Math.degToRad(this.getRollDeg()), - THREE.Math.degToRad( this.getHeadingDeg()) , - THREE.Math.degToRad(this.getPitchDeg()), 'XYZ' );
// this.sphericImageMesh_.setRotationFromEuler(euler);

// this.sphericImageMesh_.rotateZ(THREE.Math.degToRad(-this.getPitchDeg()));
// this.sphericImageMesh_.rotateX(THREE.Math.degToRad(-this.getRollDeg()));
this.sphericImageMesh_.rotateY(THREE.Math.degToRad(-this.getHeadingDeg()));
```

I have seen about use of ***`Quaternions`*** and ***`MatrixX4`*** and am not sure how to apply it. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you might try re-ordering the rotations. I think it defaults to XYZ, but I find YXZ or YZX works more intuitively. use n.rotation.order('YXZ'); and see if it doesn't behave closer to what you're thinking of. If you're doing a flightsim where +Z is forward, this will work more intuitively. You yaw, then pitch, then roll.

https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/math/Euler

Comment: It didn't work, I tried all the order combinations, or should I use kappa, omega, phi instead of yaw, roll and pitch

Comment: ? did you read the documentation i linked? Yaw pitch and roll are not keywords for THREEjs, nor are kappa omega phi. I was just using flightsim terminology. Include a fiddle with your project and describe the behavior you're looking for. "it didn't work" can mean lots of things.